# spring mvc - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring

I checked the threads concerning this and none is helping me. I am new to spring and I get this error when I try to send request values by parameter.

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/receipt", params = "id", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(@PathVariable String id, ModelMap model){
    return "receipt"
}
```

Now when I try to access the url using the url: localhost:8080/url/receipt?id=10, i get that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare id as PathVariable, but you pass it as a RequestParamter.

If you want to access your function with url: localhost:8080/url/receipt?id=10, you should change you function to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/receipt",  method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id){
    return "receipt";
}
```

Comment: 1 thing I want to add is that the default required value of @RequestParam is true, so it doesn't need to specify it.